# goでのzipファイルダウンロード処理がうまく行かない

Tags: javascript, go

CSVファイルと画像ファイルをZIPファイルアーカイブにして、そのZIPファイルをサーバーに保存して、同じzipファイルをクライアント側に送信するという処理をしたいです。

しかし、サーバーに保存されたzipファイルにはCSVファイルも画像ファイルも格納されており中身も正常なのですが、クライアントに送信して保存されるZIPファイルは開けない状況です。
下記のコードが該当するクライアントにレスポンスを返す部分なのですが、何か問題ありますでしょうか？
※createzipfileはzipに追加するcsvの情報や画像の情報などの処理です。

```golang
// ZIPファイルの作成
err = createZipFile(zipFileName, csvFileName, imageFileNames)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("ZIPファイルの作成に失敗:", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

// 作成したZIPファイルをレスポンスに書き込む
zipFile, err := os.Open(zipFileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("ZIPファイルのオープンに失敗:", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
defer zipFile.Close()

// ZIPファイルをレスポンスに書き込む
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.zip")
_, err = io.Copy(w, zipFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("ZIPファイルの書き込みに失敗:", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

また、レスポンスを受け付けるJavaScriptも下記に記載します。

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/createZipFileHandler',
        data: sendData,
        success: function (data) {
            // ダウンロード後にCSVデータを表示する処理を呼び出す
            displayCSVData();
            
            // ダウンロード後のメッセージを表示
            alert('ZIPファイルがダウンロードされました。');

            // CSVデータの表示欄を表示する
            $(".csvDataContainer").show();
 
            // ZIP ファイルのダウンロード処理
            var csvData = data; // サーバーからのレスポンスはすでにZIPデータ
            var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'application/csv' });
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "data.csv"; // ダウンロード時のファイル名を指定
            link.click();

            /*// ファイルポインターをファイルの先頭に戻す
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);*/
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("通信エラー");
        },
    });
}
```